# Embedded framework build directory not matching scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have several frameworks embedded in my Xcode workspace. In my scheme list, I have four schemes - 2 products: 1 release, 1 beta version of each. Each scheme has its own info.plist, product name, build settings, build path. In my main scheme, my app will build and archive correctly.

When I change to the alternate scheme (release or beta) I get a build error because my embedded frameworks are building in the original build/Release-iphoneos directory and not the build/Release AlternateName-iphoneos. I have tried everything I can think of to get my Framework SearchPaths and Library SearchPaths to point to the embedded framework build directory but I'm having no luck.

Has anyone run into this problem before or have any suggestions? Would the best solution be to have a run script phase that copies the embedded builds into the target directory?